# Async/await restrictions

Tags: c#, async-await

What are other restrictions on using `async` with a method signature and on using `await` with an expression in these methods, if there are any? So far, I am aware that a method marked with `async` can have only one of the following return types (maybe there are more?).

- `void`
- `Task`
- `Task<TResult>`

Comment: _"The task to which the await operator is applied typically is the return value from a call to a method that **implements the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern**. Examples include values of type Task or Task<TResult>"_

Comment: @gdoron Much better comment than the former one.

Comment: The real answer is not that there are no other restrictions, there are even less.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have an [intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

`await` only requires that it be passed an instance that is "awaitable" (matching a certain pattern, similar to how `foreach` works). The most common awaitables are tasks, but there are others (e.g., Windows Store asynchronous operations).

`async` must be used on any method that uses `await`. `async` methods must return `Task` or `Task<T>`, or, if you absolutely must, `void`.

Answer (score 6):

The `async` modifier is only allowed on methods with a return type of `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>`.  In general, it *should* only be used on methods which include an `await` operator.

The `await` operator can be used on any type *t* where (From C# language spec, 7.7.7):

> t has an accessible instance or extension method called GetAwaiter with no parameters and no type parameters, and a return type A for which all of the following hold:
>
> - A implements the interface System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion
> - A has an accessible, readable instance property IsCompleted of type bool
> - A has an accessible instance method GetResult with no parameters and no type 
>     parameters

In practice, this typically means you can use `await` on any `Task`, `Task<T>`, `IAsyncOperation`, `IAsyncOperation<T>` (from Windows Store API), and a few other select types in the framework.

Comment: Thanks, this is want I was looking for... I saw this in @jonskeet demo code

Answer (score 3):

You have hit upon the major *technical* constraints of `async` methods.  I would offer this additional guidance:

1. It is pointless to declare an `async` method which does not `await` at least one operation, as such a method is equivalent to a regular, synchronous method.
2. You should avoid writing `async void` methods.  These are intended only to support the writing of asynchronous event handlers.
3. If you *call* an `async` method, you should `await` it (or at least access the Task's `IsFaulted` status and retrieve its `Exception` if one occurred).  If you do not, and one of the awaited operations inside that method throws an exception that you do not catch, that exception will be rethrown on the finalizer thread<sup>1</sup> (bad).

You can `await` any object with an awaitable type, i.e., a type which declares a member:

```
TAwaiter GetAwaiter();
```

Where `TAwaiter` is a type declaring the following members:

```
bool IsCompleted { get; }
TResult GetResult();
void OnCompleted(Action continuation);  // inherited from INotifyCompletion
```

The `IsCompleted` property is self-describing: it returns `true` if the awaitable operation has already completed; otherwise, it returns false.

The `GetResult()` method returns the result of the operation, or returns `void` if the operation has no return type.  It should throw if called while `IsCompleted` is `false`.

The `OnCompleted()` method is used to register a continuation, i.e., the code which is called upon completion of the operation.  This member should actually be inherited from `INotifyCompletion` in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace (all awaiters should implement this interface).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This is no longer the default behavior in .NET 4.5, though it can still be enabled on the client machine through a configuration change.</sub>

Comment: Good answer except for (3). By default, [unobserved task exceptions are no longer raised on a thread pool or finalizer thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx) (as of .NET 4.5).

Comment: @StephenCleary Added a footnote.  Even though it's not the _default_ behavior in .NET 4.5, it can still be enabled in the user's machine configuration (or app configuration).  Since the effect is application-wide, it's best not to assume the default behavior.